# Change notification style

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-styles

does anyone know how to define style like mediastyle for notifications in android. I want to use different background color for notification that appear on devices who has android version 5.0 or above. I want to use same color, but I want to use different height of notification, and I don't want a buttons in notification. Currently I use custom view for notification that has same background color like medaistyle notification, but custom view appears only on devices that has version of android lower then 5.0 . Can anyone help please

Thank you very much